# Python cut array into two arrays using indices array

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array, let's say arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
and another indices array: idx = [0, 3, 4, 6]

and I want to get two arrays, one is only those indices from arr: [1, 4, 5, 7]
and another one is all the rest: [2, 3, 6, 8]

Can someone help me with that? I can only think of ugly ways to do it, but it must be some function that does it elegantly.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You could do it like this:

```
selected = [arr[i] for i in idx]
other = [v for i, v in enumerate(arr) if i not in idx]
```

If `arr` has no duplicates, you could also do:

```
other = [v for v in arr if v not in selected]
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Way to do it:

```
a1 = [arr[x] for x in idx] 
a2 = [x for x in arr if x not in a1]
```

Answer (score 2):

With one traversal:

```
no, yes = both = [], []
for i, x in enumerate(arr):
    both[i in idx].append(x)
```

Or (as commented by Chris_Rands):

```
yes, no = [], []
for i, x in enumerate(arr):
    (yes if i in idx else no).append(x)
```

Though `idx` should either be small for this or turned into a set (same goes for the solutions in the other answers, I guess they just don't want to talk about it).

Demo:

```
>>> if 1:
    arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
    idx = [0, 3, 4, 6]
    no, yes = both = [], []
    for i, x in enumerate(arr):
        both[i in idx].append(x)
    print('yes', yes)
    print('no', no)

yes [1, 4, 5, 7]
no [2, 3, 6, 8]
```

Comment: @Chris_Rands Hmm, what if I rename `both` to `noyes` or `no_yes`?

Comment: Well it's subjective I guess, but personally I prefer the other way, plus it might be less confusing for beginners perhaps

Comment: @Chris_Rands Ok, I'll add it. I thought one reason I started using mine was that it was faster, but I just timed it again and it was slower. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is a neat solution with `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.asarray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])  # converts your list in numpy array
idx1 = [0, 3, 4, 6]
idx2 = [1, 2, 5, 7]

arr1 = arr[idx1]  # [1 4 5 7]
arr2 = arr[idx2]  # [2 3 6 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools` for a one line solution:

```
import itertools
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
idx = [0, 3, 4, 6]
[(out_index, not_in_arr), (in_index, in_arr)] = [(a, list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(arr, key=lambda x:arr.index(x) in idx), key=lambda x:arr.index(x) in idx)]
print(not_in_arr)
print(in_arr)
```

Output:

```
[2, 3, 6, 8]
[1, 4, 5, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also map each value in `arr` to a dictionary, indicating if it's index is present in `idx`:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
idx = [0, 3, 4, 6]

# converted to a set
idx_lookup = set(idx)

d = {x: True if i in idx_lookup else False for i, x in enumerate(arr)}
print(d)
```

Which gives this dictionay:

```
{1: True, 2: False, 3: False, 4: True, 5: True, 6: False, 7: True, 8: False}
```

I also converted `idx` to a set since in this case, duplicate indices are not necessary, and set/dictionary lookup is `O(1)`. However, list lookup is `O(n)`, so this optimization is worth it if possible.

Once you have this dictionary,  you can [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) out the elements you want to keep, and the rest of the elements from this:

```
keep = list(filter(lambda x: d[x], arr))
rest = list(filter(lambda x: not d[x], arr))

print(keep)
print(rest)
```

Which Outputs:

```
[1, 4, 5, 7]
[2, 3, 6, 8]
```

**Note:** You can also use list comprehensions above filtering of `keep` and `rest`:

```
keep = [x for x in arr if d[x]]
rest = [x for x in arr if not d[x]]
```